How to ignore "unused expression" warning from Pylance when using bit-shift operator to compose relationships in airflow
I am currently developing Airflow DAGs using Python. I am using:

Mypy version: 1.8.0
Python version: 3.11.9
VSCode version: 1.92.2
Pylance version: v2024.8.2

When I use the bit-shift operator to compose the relationships between different Operators, I have this warning in VSCode:
Expression value is unused

I would like to keep type checking enabled in VSCode, but I don't want to see this warning for valid use cases like composing Airflow DAGs.
Is there a way to configure Pylance to suppress this specific warning for the bit-shift operator?
I tried to set a mypy.ini in my settings with the code below, it doesnt do anything.
[mypy]
warn_unused_ignores = False

The VSCode mypy extension settings look like:

Can anyone help me figure out how to resolve this issue without disabling type checking entirely?

I think the warning isn't from Mypy.

I know nothing about Airflow so this may not help but you can suppress the warning (coming from Pylance) by adding a special form of comment after the expression - viz. start >> log_user_id >> tg1_object >> end # type: ignore

@SIGHUP thank you, I should have mentionned that I several hundreds of bit-shifts operator, I wanted to find something more durable

@mkrieger1 I deactivated pylance and installed the extension: mypy-type-checker, it works for now, I will try to tweak some settings to match my use case. I wanted mypy to act as a linter, next to black and ruff.

you can try to disable semantic highlighting by changing editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled to false. Similarly, there is also the option to disable the Pylance extension. Or add [REPORTS] unused-expression =no to the .pylintrc ignore unused expression warnings. Then restart the vscode attempt.
